# How to post deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I posted [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13900/disk-file-effects-of-delete-and-vacuum) and soon after deleted it. Now some days later I think it is a good question and want to repost it. When I try to post the system refuses it saying it is a duplicate and showing the link to the deleted question which if followed returns a 404 page. Is it possible to undelete a question? If not is there any other solution than rewriting it?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but not for you, it would have to be for a mod to undelete. The best way to do that is to post on meta and ask for our help.

But be aware that this being a hardware question, it might not be so well answered here. If you want to focus on the semantics of the hardware, you might also consider asking on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ altho it might also be offtopic for them. Just a thought.